Context-aware provider initialisation in Flutter
I'm using the following way to init each provider when needed and dispose them. Currently i'm running into an issue where I can't access the same provider instance if I move to another screen.
class ScreenWrapper<T extends ChangeNotifier> extends StatelessWidget {
  final T Function() builder;
  final Widget child;

  const ScreenWrapper({super.key, required this.builder, required this.child});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ChangeNotifierProvider<T>(
      create: (context) => builder(),
      child: child,
    );
  }
}

I tried Provider.of<PROVIDER_NAME>(context); but it spits out ProviderNotFoundException.
Can anyone help me on this please?
